# Using timezone 'EST' in freemarker template

Tags: java, timezone, freemarker

```
<#setting time_zone="America/New_York">
Time: ${response.currentDate?string("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a zzz")}.
```

I need the timezone to be displayed as 'EST'.
But currently, when i run the application and the email gets generated from the template above, it is displaying as 'EDT'.

Can you please let me know what needs to be done to show as 'EST'?
The current timezone (on the system where I am testing) is Indian Standard Time

Thanks!

Comment: Why would the time zone display as EST? It's *not* currently EST in New York - it's EDT, Eastern Daylight Time. If it said EST, it would be lying.

Comment: You are correct, my question's got answered. Thanks a lot!

Refer: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is expected at this point of year.
Refer: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/edt.html

(thanks to the above comment by Jon)

Answer (score 1):

try `<#setting time_zone="US/Eastern">`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the comments and the answers before posting. In this case, you can see the question has already been solved: one of the answers has a green check beside them. However, if you can add important information, another answer is welcome.